# Identifying birth family of Heinrich Ernst Walter in Markendorf, Hannover, Germany?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, birth-records

Heinrich Ernst (or Ernst Heinrich) Walter was born March 15, 1867 in Markendorf, Hannover (now in Niedersachsen/Lower Saxony), Germany.

He had sisters Lena, Clara, and Etta and brothers Fred and Charles and maybe more siblings.

How can I identify his birth family?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Questions that are "looking for any information on this family" are not a good fit for our site -- please take the [tour] and read the material in the [help]. You can edit your post to say what sources you've already looked at and add other information by using the edit link underneath your question.  We encourage community members to write specific research questions -- it is okay to write multiple questions about the same family and link back to previous questions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to identifying the birth family (his parents and siblings) of Heinrich/Ernst will be to find a birth/baptism record for him which may name his parents/father.

If you cannot locate one then you could seek indirect records of his birth.

Once you know his parents then you would expect any other births/baptisms to the same parents, in the same location and time period to be his siblings.

You seem to know that he was born March 15, 1867 in "Markendorf, Hannover, Germany" so a starting point to find the records that you seem may be the [Hannover Online Genealogy Records](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Hannover_Online_Genealogy_Records) of FamilySearch.org:

> These are genealogy links to Hannover online databases to assist in
>   researching your family history. This Online Collection has links to
>   online databases and indexes that may include birth records, marriage
>   records, death records, biographies, cemeteries, censuses, histories,
>   immigration records, land records, military records, newspapers,
>   obituaries, or probate records.